# save mysql php select values

Tags: php, mysql, select

How do I save the select value to the MySQL database

```html
<select multiple id="id" name="althizmet[]">
<option value="0">Deger</option>
<option value="1">Deger2</option>
<option value="2">Deger3</option>
</select>

<?php
foreach ($_POST["althizmet"] as $selectedOption)
{    
    $vay= $selectedOption;
}
$baglanti=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$f=mysql_select_db("data",$baglanti);
@mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
@mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
$ekle=mysql_query("INSERT INTO siparis (hizmet) VALUES ('".$vay."')");
?>
```

That's what happens: http://imgim.com/6183inciy3822365.jpg not a single one, all of them should make a record

a line selected values of How do I save all?
thank you

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: Please, show us what you tried to insert multiple elements. Edit your question and add what  you did so far to enable the feature you seek to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `foreach` to the end and move the `$ekle` line in it;

So the last line is

```
 foreach($_POST["althizmet"] as $selectedOption)
 {
   $vay = $selectedOption;
   $ekle=mysql_query("INSERT INTO siparis (hizmet) VALUES ($vay)");
 }
```

Cleaned it up a bit as there should be no reason to store a `\n` into a MYSQL variable.

Comment: dont fun a query in a loop, concatenate the data and run the query once

Comment: \n remove.. enter the loop